# Is there a way to use pylast to get the top tracks?

Tags: python, api, spotify, last.fm, pylast

I need to use the pylast module and last.fm api to get the top tracks (https://www.last.fm/api/show/chart.getTopTracks) but I can't find how to do this in python.

```py
API_KEY = "my key"
API_SECRET = "my secret"

network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY)

print(network.chart_get_top_tracks())
```

But the `chart_get_top_tracks()` method doesn't exist. how do I use this?
If it helps, my end result will hopefully be a live Spotify playlist of the top 100 songs. It will hopefully update every 10 mins or so. I've got the `playlist_add_items()` working with Spotify and now all I need is to find a way to get the top 100 and use them both together.

I tried `pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY).network.chart_get_top_tracks()` and I was hoping for it to return 50 top tracks but this method is not the real one. Am I doing something completely wrong or do I just not know the method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `network.get_top_tracks()`, not `network.chart_get_top_tracks()`:

```py
import pylast

API_KEY = "TODO"

network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key=API_KEY)
tracks = network.get_top_tracks()

for track in tracks[:10]:
    print(track.item)
```

Outputs:

```
Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero
Drake - Rich Flex
Taylor Swift - Lavender Haze
Taylor Swift - Snow on the Beach (feat. Lana Del Rey)
Taylor Swift - Midnight Rain
Taylor Swift - Karma
Taylor Swift - Maroon
Taylor Swift - You're On Your Own, Kid
Steve Lacy - Bad Habit
Taylor Swift - Bejeweled
```